# SQL Where Date is greater than X

Tags: mysql, sql, report

I am trying to run the query;

```
SELECT PO_PurchaseOrderDetail.ItemCodeDesc,   
       PO_PurchaseOrderDetail.QuantityOrdered, 
       PO_PurchaseOrderDetail.QuantityReceived, 
        PO_PurchaseOrderDetail.UnitCost, 
       PO_PurchaseOrderDetail.JT158_WTSalesOrderNo, 
       PO_PurchaseOrderDetail.PurchaseOrderNo, 
       PO_PurchaseOrderHeader.PurchaseName, 
       PO_PurchaseOrderHeader.PurchaseOrderDate
FROM PO_PurchaseOrderDetail PO_PurchaseOrderDetail, PO_PurchaseOrderHeader PO_PurchaseOrderHeader
WHERE (PO_PurchaseOrderDetail.PurchaseOrderNo=PO_PurchaseOrderHeader.PurchaseOrderNo) 
AND ***(PO_PurchaseOrderHeader.PurchaseOrderDate > '2013-12-31')***
ORDER BY PO_PurchaseOrderDetail.JT158_WTSalesOrderNo, PO_PurchaseOrderDetail.PurchaseOrderNo
```

My problem is, that the date is stored in the YYYY-MM-DD format. I need to only show data after a certain date. So, because 2013-12-31 is a string rather than a number, the operator > doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: data type of PO_PurchaseOrderHeader.PurchaseOrderDate is....?

Comment: The date in the table is stored as YYYY-MM-DD. I can't tell you what the field is actually set to. The database is proprietary and does not allow me to see such things.

Comment: if PO_PurchaseOrderHeader.PurchaseOrderDate is of  DATE datatype then it will work else you need to convert it to date time

Comment: Well, what I have does not work so I'm going to assume that it is not the DATE datatype. How can I convert it to date time?

Comment: cast(PO_PurchaseOrderHeader.PurchaseOrderDate as date) > '2013-12-31').

Comment: @KoushikVeldanda I got the same exact error as I got bellow

Comment: This doesn't sound right. Regardless of whether it's the right data type or not, it should be evaluated correctly. I feel like there's some piece of information missing from your explanation, but without seeing the table structure, it's really hard to help.

Comment: Yes. This is for a Sage ERP 100. You can't see table structure. Just the table names and fields.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `CAST` string as `DATE` in following:

P.S. if `PurchaseOrderDate` is not DATE datatype you could also CAST It: `CAST(PO_PurchaseOrderHeader.PurchaseOrderDate AS DATE)`

```
SELECT PO_PurchaseOrderDetail.ItemCodeDesc,
       PO_PurchaseOrderDetail.QuantityOrdered,
       PO_PurchaseOrderDetail.QuantityReceived, 
       PO_PurchaseOrderDetail.UnitCost, 
       PO_PurchaseOrderDetail.JT158_WTSalesOrderNo, 
       PO_PurchaseOrderDetail.PurchaseOrderNo, 
       PO_PurchaseOrderHeader.PurchaseName, 
       PO_PurchaseOrderHeader.PurchaseOrderDate
FROM   PO_PurchaseOrderDetail PO_PurchaseOrderDetail, 
       PO_PurchaseOrderHeader PO_PurchaseOrderHeader
WHERE  PO_PurchaseOrderDetail.PurchaseOrderNo = PO_PurchaseOrderHeader.PurchaseOrderNo AND    
       PO_PurchaseOrderHeader.PurchaseOrderDate > CAST('2013-12-31' AS DATE)
ORDER BY PO_PurchaseOrderDetail.JT158_WTSalesOrderNo, 
         PO_PurchaseOrderDetail.PurchaseOrderNo
```

Comment: I get this error. Which unless I'm blind, I am not missing any ). [link](http://prntscr.com/6o4w5t)

Comment: In code which I gave not missing any `)` paste your code which you use, problem should be somewhere else.

Comment: I used your exact code. I copied and pasted from yours.

Comment: Doesn't make sense. There is nothing missing in this query.